# ffmpeg avformat_open_input not working in device

Tags: iphone, c++, ios, ffmpeg

I have a method in an iOS project that calls `avformat_open_input()`, it runs very well in the simulator, however, when I try to run it on the device it hangs up and just stays there.

Has anyone seen this before?, Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That method establishes a connection to the source via URL, RTSP, RTP, etc, if it's hanging up:

1. Make sure that the source is in fact streaming data at that address and port
2. Make sure that you are connected to the right network if this is a local connection.

Please let me know how it works out.

Comment: It worked, it turns out that we have a local network setup as the source that I was not pointing to... I know, pretty dumb!. Thanks